# Displaying all Images within a Folder using php

Tags: php, image, directory

I've used this php code within my html in order to display all pictures within a folder called uploads. The only problem is that icons images are the only type of image being displayed. What have I done wrong?

```
<?php
$files = glob("uploads/*.*");

$colCnt=0;
echo '<table border="1" style="width:590px;">';

for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
$colCnt++;
if ($colCnt==1)
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td width="25%" style="font-size:8.5px; font-family:arial">';

$num = $files[$i];
echo '<img src="'.$num.'" align="absmiddle" /> ';
print substr(substr($num,6,100),0,-4);`

echo '</td>';

if ($colCnt==4)
{
echo '</tr>';
$colCnt=0;
  }
}

echo '</table>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop seems to be ok.

You have to focus on the result coming from

```
$files = glob("uploads/*.*");
```

Try `print_r($files)` to get the list and then see if it is selecting all the images properly or not.